# use "processing-java" in Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, runtime, processing

Hi I want to compile and run a .pde file (Processing) in a Processing sketch, I found out the command `processing-java --sketch=[path] --run` and it worked very well in my Terminal, but when I try to use it inside a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, it shows me the error message:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "processing-java": error=2, No such file or directory

code:

```
String sketchpath = "/Users/yangwang/Documents/NMASpaceOS/NMAexhibition_file_collection/project0/";

String cmd = "processing-java --sketch=" + sketchpath + " --run";

println(cmd);
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
catch(Exception e) {
  println(e);
}
```

if i simply copy and paste `cmd` in terminal, it will compile and run the sketch with no problem.

Comment: Please post the code you’re using that demonstrates the issue

Comment: @Krease thx for reminding, just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just need to add the PATH in front of the command. 
first I need to check the path to the command using `which processing-java`
then copy&paste the path in front of the command.

the final command is:

`"/usr/local/bin/processing-java --sketch=" + sketchFolderPath + " --run"`